# Send 2 numbers on google to calculate

Tags: html, search

I need to make an html page that contains 3 input boxes, 2 for numbers and 1 for the operator between them. They should be sent to google search to calculate the result. All operations work except for the "+" one, can someone make it work for adding the numbers as well?

```
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    First Number: <input type="text" id="num1"/><br />
    Operator: <input type="text" id="oper" /><br />
    Second Number: <input type="text" id="num2" /><br />
    <button onclick="send()">Submit</button>



<script type="text/javascript">
        function send(){
            var value = document.getElementById("num1").value+document.getElementById("oper").value+document.getElementById("num2").value+"=";
            window.location.href = "https://www.google.com/#q="+value;
        }
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it's not working with the **+** operation because it is usable on common text searches and is accounted for when you make a text search on Google.

Try encoding the **+** character as **%2b** on the URL.

Like this:

https://www.google.com/search?q=2%2b4